# Windows Form dentro de Windows Form

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Além de utilizar SplitContainer, há alguma outra maneira de colocar um Form dentro de um outro form, utilizando com estilo de iframe do HTML? Pois o SplitContainer não estou conseguindo alterar os dados da Form dentro dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andei pesquisando, existem muitas formas de realizar isso, aqui esta uma lista com possibilidades e tentativas que você pode fazer:

### Exemplo I

Coloque esse método na classe base (em que vai adicionar os controles):

```
Public Function PerformControls(ByVal Expression As Form) As Control
  Dim tmp As New Control With
     {
         .Size = Expression.Size,
         .Location = Expression.Location,
         .Cursor = Expression.Cursor,
         .Font = Expression.Font,
         .BackColor = Expression.BackColor,
         .ForeColor = Expression.ForeColor
     }
  For Each item As Object In Expression.Controls
     tmp.Controls.Add(item)
  Next
  Return tmp
End Function
```

Para usar, tente assim:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As [Object], e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Me.Controls.Add(PerformControls(New FormDest)) 'FormDest é o nome da classe destino
End Sub
```

### Exemplo II

Adicione essa função:

```
 Public Shared Sub ShowFormInControl(ByRef ctl As Control, ByRef frm As Form)
     If ctl IsNot Nothing AndAlso frm IsNot Nothing Then
         frm.TopLevel = False
         frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
         frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
         frm.Visible = True
         ctl.Controls.Add(frm)
    End If
 End Sub
```

Para usar:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As [Object], e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     ShowFormInControl(Me, New frmDest)
End Sub
```

Tente fazer isso, boa sorte.

Comment: Já tinha tentando, informa erro: Não é possível adicionar o controle de nível superior a um controle.

Comment: Tente colocar: `Dim frmHost As Control = FormDest.AtacchedControl`.

Comment: Informa erro: Não é possível adicionar o controle de nível superior a um controle.